# Robbers - square times square root

Tags: code-golf, number, arithmetic, cops-and-robbers

**Task:** Crack the scrambled code for multiplying the square root of an integer ***n*** by the square of it!

You must post a comment in the **[cops' thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/115036/cops-square-times-square-root)** with a link to your working source, mentioning clearly that you have ***Cracked it***. In your answer's title, you must include the link to the original answer.

### Rules:

- You may only change the order of the characters in the original source.
- Safe answers cannot be cracked anymore.
- The other rules mentioned in the cops' thread
- ***Please edit the answer you crack***

---

### WINNER: Emigna - 10 submissons (had some trouble counting)

*Honorable mentions: Notjagan, Plannapus, TEHTMI*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [NO](https://github.com/ValyrioCode/NO), 41 bytes, [This Guy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115253/47066)

```
NOOOOOO?NOOOOOOOOOOO!nnOOOOO
NOOOOOOOO?no
```

Comment: Really? Well at least I got my language known.

Comment: @ThisGuy: You've made some fun languages :) Not terribly useful in general though ;)

Comment: Look at the 2nd [paragraph](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115150/66833)

Answer (score 9):

## JavaScript (ES7), [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115127)

```
_26_=>_26_**6.25**.5
```

The hard part, of course, was figuring out what to do with all the extra characters.  (And also not posting this solution in the wrong thread, like I accidentally did at first.  Oopsie...)

Comment: @SethWhite: I had to use all the characters that Neil used in his scrambled code, otherwise this wouldn't have been a valid crack.

Comment: How does this work?

Comment: @Arjun `_26_=>` defines an anonymous function taking one parameter called `_26_` (variables may start with an underscore but not a number). Then the remainder is just using `**` as `Math.pow()` to raise the input to the power of 2.5 (6.25 power 0.5).

Comment: Ah! I was thinking that `_26_` was something ES7 specific. Didn't know that variables can be in this form too! (I have never seen a variable without an alphabet). That was a very clever approach by @Neil. And you were very clever too in cracking it! Have your well-deserved +1! :)

Answer (score 6):

## Python, 15 bytes, [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115064/41805)

```
lambda x:x**2.5
```

Pretty simple. Just takes `x` and raises it to the `2.5`th power.

Answer (score 6):

### OCaml, 13 bytes, [shooqie](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115068/55508)

```
fun f->f**2.5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ocaml#@19QlJlXEp@Wk59YoqGRVpqnkKZrl6alZaRnqqlgqaf5/z8A)

Comment: I was posting it right now! Cannot believe it! Good job!

Answer (score 5):

## Python 3, 44  bytes, [Kyle Gullion](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115855/15858)

Those `*`s were quite misleading. Very clever!

```python
lambda i:i**(lambda o,r:o/r)(*map(ord,'i*'))
```

Due to the quite limited character set I would be very surprised if there were any other valid solutions beyond trivial renaming or reordering of arguments.

Comment: You got me, nicely done!

Answer (score 4):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 100 bytes, [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115067/66323)

```cpp
#include<math.h>
#include"iostream"
using namespace std;int main(){float n;cin>>n;cout<<pow(n,2.5);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cpp-gcc#NcgxCsMwDADAPa8w6ZJAmyGQIdj4L0JRa0EshVimQ@mzO7tdOh1cu7DgXjcKGSxNKXb/6FmLnQS572pheTiBTOUAJFds8yzmMrAM4@u@K5gTjywx/tBqIRz6HOQ6T8vo362tH9EbAib6Ag)

Comment: Well done! Please edit the answer you crack, because I cannot do it now!

Comment: An anonymous user suggested an edit to save 8 bytes by removing the `using` and just doing `int main(){float n;std::cin>>n;std::cout<<pow(n,2.5);}`

Comment: Save another byte #including <cmath> instead of math.h.:)

Answer (score 4):

### Haskell, [Leo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115077/34531)

```
x=exp.(2.5*).log
```

A pointfree function named `x`. Usage: `x 4` -> `32.0`

Answer (score 4):

## [Inform 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inform#Inform_7), [corvus_192](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115121)

Cool, an Inform7 entry. :)  I just had to give this one a try.

I'm pretty sure this is the intended solution:

```
R is a room.

To f (n - number): say "[n * n * real square root of n]".
```

Note that this solution only works if compiled with the Glulx back-end, due to the use of the `real square root of` function.

---

BTW, the double quotes and square brackets are actually unnecessary; just `say n * n * real square root of n` would work just as well.  The periods at the end of the commands could be omitted, too; or we could keep the first period and get rid of the newlines instead.  Other parts of the code we could trim away include the article "a" before "room" and the spaces before the parentheses and after the colon.  Fortunately, since we've got a spare pair of brackets, we can always use them to comment out all these extra characters. ;) So this is a valid solution, too:

```
R is room.To f(n - number):say n * n * real square root of n[
" a . "
]
```

---

To test this solution interactively, it's convenient to append something like the following test harness to the code:

```
Effing is an action applying to one number.
Understand "f [number]" as effing.
Carry out effing: f the number understood.
```

After compiling and running the program, you can type e.g. `f 4. f 6. f 9. f 25` at the `>` prompt and receive something like the following output:

```
Welcome
An Interactive Fiction
Release 1 / Serial number 170404 / Inform 7 build 6L38 (I6/v6.33 lib 6/12N) SD

R

>f 4. f 6. f 9. f 25
32.0
88.18164
243.0
3125.0
>
```

BTW, I just noticed that Inform (or presumably, rather, Glulx) rounds the last decimal place of `f 6` wrong: the correct value is *much* closer to 88.18163 than to 88.18164.  Fortunately, I don't think this affects the correctness of the solution(s), especially since the challenge specified "any rounding mechanism of your choice". :)

Comment: I'm sure I found an Inform 7 fiddle a while ago, but I can't find it when I search. Do you know if there is an online interpreter anywhere?

Comment: @Flounderer: I don't really know of any. There are certainly online (even JS-based) players for the Glulx / Z-machine bytecode produced by the Inform 7 compiler, but I'm not aware of anything that would directly take plain Inform 7 source code and compile and run it online. The compiler / IDE is pretty easy to install, though; on Ubuntu Linux, it's as easy as `apt-get install gnome-inform7`.

Answer (score 4):

### Mathematica, [Greg Martin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115103/66104)

```
f[y_]:=With[{x=
    #&@@{#(#)#^(1/(1+1))&@y,#&@@@{1^(1),-1}}
},Print[#,".",IntegerString[Round@#2,10,3]]&@@QuotientRemainder[1000x,1000]]
```

Thanks for leaving the rounding stuff intact!

Explanation: `#(#)#^(1/(1+1))&@y` does the main work of multiplying `y` squared, aka `y(y)`, and `y`'s square root, `y^(1/(1+1))`. The `#&@@@{1^(1),-1}` bit is just junk to use up the other letters, and `#&@@` picks out the useful bit from the junk.

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 12 bytes, [Luis Mendo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115071/49958)

```
10'U&+:'n/^P
```

Calculate 10/4 = 2.5 with 4 coming from string length. Use this as an exponent. P is a no-op here.

Answer (score 3):

### [R, Steadybox](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115093/26905)

```
y<-function(p)(p^(1/2)*p^2);
```

seems to be an anagram of `funny(p1)-tio(^*^)/pc(2)<p2;`

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 60 bytes, [Anthony Pham](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115118/63641)

```
print    (input()**(5.0/(2*5554448893999/5554448893840))-0)
```

Based on discarding characters through Python 2's float division (the default for `/` between integers).

Answer (score 3):

## C, 50 bytes, [Dave](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115130/66323)

```c
double b(float \ufa2d){return pow(\ufa2d,25e-1);%>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#U87MS84pTUlVsCkuScnM18uw@5@SX5qUk6qQpJGWk59YohBTmpZolKJZXZRaUlqUp1CQX64BEdIxMk3VNdS0VrX7n5lXopCbmJmnoalQzcVZUATkp2koqabF5CnpAA0yMtXUtOaq/f8vOS0nMb34v25OLgA)

This requires `-lm` compiler flag, but I don't know how it would be possible to solve this without it.

Comment: correct, and almost exactly what I had (variable was named `\uad2f` on mine). Well done; I thought I'd left enough red-herrings in there to keep people busy a lot longer! Also the `-lm` flag wasn't needed for me using Clang (I'd have mentioned it!) but you're correct that strictly speaking it's required.

Answer (score 3):

## R, [Flounderer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115133/6741)

This is a crack of the 33 bytes solution of @Flounderer

```
scan()^(floor(pi)-1/2)-sin(7*0e1)
```

Usage:

```
> scan()^(floor(pi)-1/2)-sin(7*0e1)
1: 4
2: 
Read 1 item
[1] 32
> scan()^(floor(pi)-1/2)-sin(7*0e1)
1: 6
2: 
Read 1 item
[1] 88.18163
> scan()^(floor(pi)-1/2)-sin(7*0e1)
1: 9
2: 
Read 1 item
[1] 243
> scan()^(floor(pi)-1/2)-sin(7*0e1)
1: 25
2: 
Read 1 item
[1] 3125
```

Comment: Yes, this is not the intended solution which involved `sin(pi)`, but unfortunately it does work! +1

Comment: It was `scan()^(-floor(-sin(pi)*2e17)/10)`

Answer (score 3):

## EXCEL, 26 Bytes [pajonk](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/115036/cops-square-times-square-root/115233#115233)

```
=SQRT(A1)*A1^2/1/ISNA(IP2)
```

A1 as input
IP2 contain a second input with a #N/A Error
in this case ISNA(IP2) belongs to 1

For an additional `()`
we can do this

```
=SQRT(A1)*A1^2/ISNA(PI(1/2))
```

Comment: Is second input allowed in such challenge?

Comment: @pajonk The rules say "You can take input in any standard way" so I have assume that you make this trick with a second input

Comment: @pajonk I have improve my post it could been that you have make a little mistake

Comment: The standard way for taking one number is (I think) taking one input. In my opinion the second input would be unfair and against the rules. PS There's no mistake in number of brackets.

Comment: @pajonk I can not use combinations with SIN and PI cause there are not enough brackets. `=SQRT(A1)*A1^2/SIN(PI()/2)` If you set the #NA Error through formating or something else I would see it as additional second input. SQRT and ISNA are the only two functions that make a little sense. But please ask the man who had developed the question

Answer (score 3):

## RProgN 2, [ATaco](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115120/63641)

```
]2^\š*
```

Apparently StackExchange needs extra characters, so here you go.

Comment: My solution was `]š\2^*`, but they both work the same way.

Answer (score 3):

## HODOR, 198, [This Guy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115262/67716)

```
Walder
Hodor?!
hodor.
Hodor, Hodor Hodor Hodor Hodor Hodor Hodor Hodor, Hodor Hodor,
hodor,
Hodor, Hodor Hodor Hodor Hodor Hodor Hodor, Hodor Hodor,
Hodor, Hodor Hodor Hodor, hodor!,
HODOR!!
HODOR!!!
```

Explanation:

```
Start
read input into accumulator
copy accumulator to storage
Do math, option 7(nth root), n=2
swap storage and accumulator
Do math, option 6(nth power), n=2
Do math, option 3(times), storage
output accumulator as a number
end
```

note: I had to make some modifications to the get interpreter to run on my machine (the one you have posted doesn't seem to accept lowercase h, among some other things)

Also, I don't seem to have enough rep to comment, so if someone could let @This Guy know, I would be grateful

I think this fixed the error, the code now starts with Walder instead of Wylis, which adds the extra byte

Comment: Almost there. Had to change a mistake in my code so yours ins't quite right.

Comment: fixed the start command

Comment: Though that you had it but you went for a different method than me that uses the same number of bytes. Your answer would do what you wanted it to do but it isn't the same as mine. Also I had to change the name because of [this](http://www.hodor-lang.org/) so I made an edit to your posts.

Comment: for clarification, does this still count as a crack, or do I need to match up exactly?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure. I'm going to ask in the comments. +1 your solution is making me think really hard!

Comment: I'm just going to give you it given that they;re basically the same. Can I edit yours to add my original code?

Comment: @ThisGuy: The crack is valid as long as the exact same characters are used (it is an anagram of the original). Doesn't matter if it is the same as the original.

Comment: @Emigna Well I've still got [NO!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115253/66833)

Answer (score 3):

### C#, 172 bytes, [raznagul](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115069/32628)

Hardest part was figuring out what to do with all the leftovers.

```
using System;using S=System.Console;class PMabddellorttuuv{static void Main(){S.Write(Math.Pow(double.Parse(S.ReadLine()),2.5));Func<double> o;int q=1,M=q*2,b,e;q*=(q*M);}}
```

Comment: Nice! I got stuck on the leftovers as well. Didn't think to add them to the class name, doh!. Good job!

Comment: +1 Not what I had intended, but very nice solution. ;)

Answer (score 3):

### Python 3.6, 64 bytes, [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115339/44706)

```
php38af4r2aoot2srm0itpfpmm0726991i=     (lambda x:x**2.5*1*1/1);
```

Maybe not what was intended, but works ;)

```
$ python3
Python 3.6.1 (default, Apr  4 2017, 09:36:47) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> php38af4r2aoot2srm0itpfpmm0726991i=     (lambda x:x**2.5*1*1/1);
>>> php38af4r2aoot2srm0itpfpmm0726991i(6)
88.18163074019441
>>> php38af4r2aoot2srm0itpfpmm0726991i(4)
32.0
>>> php38af4r2aoot2srm0itpfpmm0726991i(25)
3125.0
```

Not enough rep to comment on the cops' thread's answer yet, sorry... Would appreciate if someone could do it for me, thanks!

Comment: @Mr. Xcoder , as said above, can't comment on your post in the cops' thread, sorry about that :)

Comment: Came to post a similar solution `from math import pi as pp0012223467899;f=lambda x:x**2.5*1*(1)/1` just to see I've been beaten to the punch. I've added a link to this post on the cops thread for you.

Answer (score 3):

## [Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda/tree/roda-0.12), 28 bytes, [fergusq](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115053/49958)

```
f(n){push n^0.5,n^2|product}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2.7, [Koishore Roy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115778/64121)

```
s=e=x=y=input()**0.5
print'%.3f'%(y**(5.0))
```

Comment: Or `y=x=e=s`, both work :)) Good job anyways!

Comment: Good job. :P
Now I need to work on a new code. Darn!

Answer (score 3):

## R, [Flounderer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115133/6741)

This is a crack of @Flounderer's 31-byte solution:

```
`[.`=function(`]`)`]`^`[`(lh,9)
```

Ok that was a tough one. It creates a function called `` `[.` ``. The argument to the function is called `` `]` `` which is elevated to power 2.5 by using the 9th element of the built-in time-serie `lh` ("a regular time series giving the luteinizing hormone in blood samples at 10 mins intervals from a human female, 48 samples." that is used as example in one of R's base packages). `lh[9]` is here on top of it replaced by its equivalent `` `[`(lh, 9) ``. De-obfuscated by substituting `f` for the function name and `n` for the argument name, the function then becomes `f=function(n)n^lh[9]`.

Usage:

```
> `[.`=function(`]`)`]`^`[`(lh,9)
> `[.`(4)
[1] 32
> `[.`(6)
[1] 88.18163
> `[.`(9)
[1] 243
> `[.`(25)
[1] 3125
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 44 bytes, [Anthony Pham](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115074/64505)

```
print int(raw_input())**(0+000000000000.5*5)
```

Takes input from raw_input, converts to int and raises to power 2.5

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, [**fəˈnɛtɪk**](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/115036/cops-square-times-square-root/115058#115058)

```js
n=>n**("ggggg".length*2**(-"g".length))// ""((((((()))))))***,-...;;=====>Seeeeegggghhhhhhhhhilllnnnnnnorrrsstttttttttttu{}
```

Gets 5/2 through 5 times 2 to the negative first power, where 5 and 1 were received from the length of strings. Took the easy way out in a sense by commenting out the extraneous characters.

Answer (score 2):

### C#, 112 bytes, [Jan Ivan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115174/47066)

```
using System;class P{static void Main(){var b=Math.Pow(double.Parse(Console.ReadLine()),2.5);Console.Write(b);}}
```

Answer (score 2):

### [Fireball](https://github.com/okx-code/Fireball), 8 bytes, [Okx](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115196/56341)

```
♥²♥1Z/^*
```

Explanation:

```
♥²♥1Z/^*
♥²       Push first input squared.
  ♥      Push first input again.
   1Z/   Push 1/2
      ^  First input to the 1/2th
       * Multiply square and root
```

Not sure if it works. I have currently no java on my laptop. :(

Comment: I don't think that will work. Easy fix though, so I'll give you the answer. You just need to swap the `Z1` into `1Z`.

Comment: I was sure I did a mistake there. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 47 bytes, [Okx](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115194/47066)

```
).2555BFHIJJKKKPQRS``„cg…ghi…lsw…x}T…Áöž«‚¹n¹t*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@6@pZ2Rqaurk5uHp5eXt7R0QGBSckPCoYV5y@qOGZekZmUAyp7gcSFbUhgDJw42Htx3dd2j1o4ZZh3bmHdpZovX/vxkA)

Comment: Ah, I knew there would be a workaround the method I used to 'secure' the code. Well done!

Comment: @Okx: Yeah, 05AB1E is very tricky to pad with extra code without making it bypassable.

Comment: I'll see if I can make you a trickier one ;)

Comment: @Okx: Looking forward to it :) I have an idea as well that I may try to implement after work ;)

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 8 bytes, [Roman Gräf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115195/47066)

My First ever CJam answer.
CnR are great for testing new languages :)

```
ldYYW#+#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@5@TEhkZrqyt/P@/GQA)

**Explanation**

```
ld         % double(input)
       #   %              ^
  Y        %               (2
      +    %                 +
   Y       %                  2
     #     %                   ^
    W      %                    -1)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 64 bytes, [@nimi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115124/56433)

```hs
product.(<$>(($(succ.cos$0))<$>[(flip<$>flip)id$id,recip])).(**)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#FYwxDoAgDAC/0oGhJYY4OCov8AfGwRRJmigQwPcjTHe54ZqHDVKO7uNqcFUWUWH5mA3Homaing70j6QuAyROiZvyzZJOIoNaU3svCf2T78vtAawdSwkVDPi2/A) That was a fun one. I first found `product.(<$>(($succ(cos$0))<$>[id,recip])).(**)` which behaves correctly and than had to fit `flip flip <$> () $ id .` somewhere into it.

Answer (score 2):

## R, [steadybox](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115224/6741)

```
a222=function(s)(s**0.5)*s**2**1
```

Usage:

```
> a222=function(s)(s**0.5)*s**2**1
> a222(4)
[1] 32
> a222(6)
[1] 88.18163
> a222(9)
[1] 243
> a222(25)
[1] 3125
```

Comment: Original: `a=function(s)s**2*s**(0.125*2*2)`

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 22 bytes, [P. Knops](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115240/47066)

```
n¹t*qA9¥="'?:@->%#[{!.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@593aGeJVqGj5aGltkrq9lYOunaqytHVinr//5sBAA)

**Explanation**

```
n      # square of input
   *   # times
 ¹t    # square root of input
    q  # end program
```

The rest of the operations never get executed.
We could have done it without the `q` as well by having `?` after the calculation and escaping the equality sign for example with `'=`.

Comment: Was just doing it for fun :D

Comment: @P.Knops: That's the best reason :)

Answer (score 2):

## [HODOR](https://github.com/ValyrioCode/Hodor/), 171 bytes, [wwj](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115293/47066)

```
Walder
Hodor 
Hodor 
Hodor 
Hodor 
Hodor
Hodor, Hodor Hodor Hodor Hodor, Hodor Hodor,
hodor.
Hodor.
Hodor?!
Hodor, Hodor Hodor Hodor Hodor Hodor Hodor, hodor!,
HODOR!!
HODOR!!!
```

**Explanation**

- Increment accumulator to 5
- Divide accumulator by 2
- Save a copy of accumulator value
- Set accumulator to 0
- Read input
- Raise input to the value of the stored copy (2.5)
- Output as number

Comment: back to the drawing board

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, 39 bytes, [SLuck49](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115252/12474)

```
x=>(l=Math).cbrt(l.exp(l.log(x)*7.5))
```

or similarly

```
x=>(l=Math).exp(l.log(l.cbrt(x))*7.5)
```

Test:

```js
alert((

x=>(l=Math).cbrt(l.exp(l.log(x)*7.5))

)(prompt()));
```

Answer (score 2):

## C, 115 bytes, [user4867444](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115287/49958)

New solution that works for 0.

```
o(double n){double l=1;;for(double o=0.;o<=8*8*2e3&&(long)o+n*((long)2*3>>1);o++)l=(l+n/l)/2;printf("%.3f",n*n*l);}
```

Old solution that doesn't work for 0:

```
o(double n){double l=n;;for(double o=1.0;o<=8*8*2e+3&&(long)o*((long)2*3>>1);o++)l=(l+n/l)/2;printf("%.3f",n*n*l);}
```

Applying Newton's method (for square root) a very large fixed number of times seems to give adequate precision for numbers in the required range. I did some character wasting in the first two for loop clauses.

Comment: Close, but not quite, as it returns nan for 0 (not sure we care about that case, asked the OP in a comment)

Comment: As specified by the OP, our programs must return 0 for 0, so I'm afraid your solution doesn't work.

Comment: @user4867444: Sorry, I didn't understand that it must work for 0. I've provided a modified solution that should work for 0.

Comment: the original solution was `o(double n){long o=2.303e18+(*(long*)&n>>1);double l=*(double*)&o;for(o=2;o++<8;)l=(l+n/l)/2;printf("%.3f",l*n*n);}`, which uses a nice magic constant to only do a few Newton iterations as opposed to thousands - but great job!

Answer (score 2):

### 05AB1E, 22 bytes, [Emigna](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115251/44706)

```
è›¹DDLÏ_zTnF©¹®/+;}¹DP
```

Most probably not what was intended, but works ;)

Everything before `T` is just byte wasting (but which leaves the stack empty), then it does a 100 Newton iterations, which yields a good enough approximation of the square root, then pushes the input twice and returns the product of the whole stack, thus giving the desired output.

Example runs:

```
$ echo 0 | ./05AB1E.py -e 'è›¹DDLÏ_zTnF©¹®/+;}¹DP'
0.0
$ echo 4 | ./05AB1E.py -e 'è›¹DDLÏ_zTnF©¹®/+;}¹DP'
32.0
$ echo 6 | ./05AB1E.py -e 'è›¹DDLÏ_zTnF©¹®/+;}¹DP'
88.18163074019441
$ echo 25 | ./05AB1E.py -e 'è›¹DDLÏ_zTnF©¹®/+;}¹DP'
3125.0
$ echo 7131 | ./05AB1E.py -e 'è›¹DDLÏ_zTnF©¹®/+;}¹DP'
4294138928.896773
```

Comment: Nice one! Didn't think of that :P

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 15 bytes, [user4867444](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115613/47066)

```
DMžDFD¹s/+;}01P
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@@/ie3Sfi5vLoZ3F@trWtQaGAf//mxsaGwIA)

**Explanation**

```
D                 # duplicate input
 M                # push the largest value on the stack (the input)
  žDF             # 4096 times do:
     D            # current value
         +        # added to
      ¹s/         # input divided by current value
          ;       # divide sum by 2
           }      # end loop
            01    # push 1
              P   # product of the stack
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 23 bytes, [user4867444](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115639/47066)

```
$DDžHGD¹s/+;}0@rrzz2+\P
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@6/i4nJ0n4e7y6Gdxfra1rUGDkVFVVVG2jEB//@bAQA)

**Explanation**

```
$                        # push 1 and input
 DD                      # duplicate the input twice
   žHG                   # 65536 times do:
      D                  # duplicate current value
       ¹s/               # divide input by current value
          +              # add result of division to current value
           ;             # divide by 2
            }            # end loop
             0@          # get the bottom value of the stack (the 1)
               rr        # reverse the stack twice (no-op)
                 zz      # calculate 1/(1/1), a no-op
                   2+    # add 2
                     \   # discard top of stack (the 3)
                      P  # product of stack
```

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript](https://nodejs.org), [SIGSEGV](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/116225/47066)

```javascript
x=>x**(25*10**-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/javascript-node#@59mW2FrV6GlpWFkqmVooKWla6j5Pzk/rzg/J1UvJz9dI03DTFPzPwA)

Comment: You got it! Kudos for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

## Python - [SparklePony](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/115036/cops-square-times-square-root/115080#115080)

```
import math
f=lambda x:x*x*math.sqrt(x)
```

Comment: That was very fast!

Comment: Thanks @SparklePony. It was very similar to mine, done it right away

Comment: @SparklePony please accept the edit...

Comment: I think I have done it... first time accepting an edit!

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, [corvus_192](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115097/65425)

```
d=>math.pow(d,5/2d)
```

[Try it here!](https://codepad.remoteinterview.io/UJENSUDGIW)

Simple lambda expression

Answer (score 1):

## 05AB1E - [P. Knops](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/115036/cops-square-times-square-root/115105#115105)

```
t¹n*
```

Was quite easy :)

Answer (score 1):

## C, [Steadybox](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115102/8927)

```c
float q(float b){return(b-b>0.*4*1/1)-sqrtf(b)*pow(b,2)*-1;}
```

Not sure what the original did; I had to discard a lot of random operators and numbers, but once the available words were clear it wasn't too hard to piece together the general idea.

Comment: Oops; noticed I'd accidentally included an extra space than the original; fixed.

Comment: Here's the original function: `float q(float b){return-1*pow(b,(b>-12)/sqrt(4.0f))*b*b*-1;}`

Answer (score 1):

## R, [Flounderer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115133/61405)

```
scan()**mean(1:4.5)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/r#@19QlJlXolGcnJinoamllZsKpA2tTPRMNTX//zfhAgA)

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3.6, [c..](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115145/20260)

```python
f=lambda x:x**2.5or'1*77*8+8/5/(((aafothipie.xml)))'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#@59mm5OYm5SSqFBhVaGlZaRnml@kbqhlbq5loW2hb6qvoaGRmJiWX5KRWZCZqleRm6Opqan@v6AoM69EI03DTFPzPwA)

Stuffs all the unneeded characters into a string after the `or`. Since `x**2.5` is nonzero and so truthy, the part after the `or` isn't evaluated. Any syntactically valid expression would be OK here.

Python parses `2.5` and `or` as separate tokens in `2.5or`, though the syntax highlighter for the code doesn't recognize this.

Comment: I think you meant `x**2.5`? Damn Python, I'm doing the next one without strings.

Comment: @c.. Yes, 2.5, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, [G B](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115166/45268)

```
->a{eval''<<97<<42<<42<<50<<46<<53}
```

Comment: Nice, I was expecting that, maybe not so fast. :-)

Answer (score 1):

### C#, 135 bytes, [Jan Ivan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115492/32628)

This was a lot of fun, I particularly liked the use of `using static`.

```
using System;using static System.Math;class P{static void Main(){Console.Write(Pow(long.Parse(Console.ReadLine()),1/Round(PI-E,1)));}}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript](https://nodejs.org), [SIGSEGV](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/116225/47066)

```javascript
x=>x**(3.5-+!+[]);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/javascript-node#@59mW2FrV6GlpWGsZ6qrragdHatp/T85P684PydVLyc/XSNNw0xT8z8A)

Comment: Well, not the same, but well, that works too. *maybeIshouldn'tuseasterisks*

Comment: @SIGSEGV: I'd be interested to see what the intended version was then :)

Answer (score 0):

## Vyxal, cracks [emanresuA's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237660/78850)

```
5|2/en[(`ĖĖ:
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=5%7C2%2Fen%5B%28%60%C4%96%C4%96%3A&inputs=6&header=&footer=)

Easy. I came up with the solution in the shower that's how easy it is.

Comment: So you have, thanks to an oversight of mine. [On to round 2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237663/100664)