# Cops - square times square root

Tags: code-golf, number, arithmetic, cops-and-robbers

*Note: This is the **cops'** thread, where one should post the scrambled code. Here is the **[robbers' thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/115034/robbers-square-times-square-root)*** where the cracked source should be posted and linked to the cop's answer.

---

**Task:** Write the shortest *safe* program which multiplies the square root of an integer ***n*** by the square of ***n***

This is [cops-and-robbers](/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers), so the rules are:

- In your answer, post a scrambled version of your source code (the characters should be written in any order). The scrambled version **should not** work!
- You can take input in any standard way, the same goes for output. Hardcoding is forbidden
- After the code is cracked by the robbers (if this happens), you must mention that your code has been cracked in your title and add a ***[spoiler](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-markdown-support-for-hidden-until-you-click-text-aka-spoilers)*** to your answer's body with your exact code
- The same applies to safe answers (mention that it's safe and add the ***[spoiler](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-markdown-support-for-hidden-until-you-click-text-aka-spoilers)***)
- The code is considered *safe* if nobody has cracked it in 5 days after posting it and you can optionally specify that in the title
- You must specify your programming language
- You should specify your byte count
- You must state the rounding mechanism in your answer (see below)

---

You can assume that the result is lower than 2<sup>32</sup> and ***n*** is always positive. If the result is an integer, you must return the exact value with or without a decimal point; otherwise the minimum decimal precision will be 3 decimal places with any rounding mechanism of your choice, but can include more. **You must state the rounding mechanism in your answer.** You are not allowed to return as fractions (numerator, denominator pairs - sorry, Bash!)

#### Examples:

```
In -> Out

4 -> 32.0 (or 32)
6 -> 88.18163074019441 (or 88.182 following the rules above)
9 -> 243.0
25 -> 3125.0
```

The shortest safe answer by the end of April will be considered the winner.

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/40932/8478) (Same CnR rules, different task.)

Comment: @MartinEnder If the task is the only thing differing, then isn't it a duplicate?

Comment: @NathanMerrill I don't know, I don't think we have any established duplicate guidelines for cops and robbers challenge, but if I ask a new [tag:code-golf] challenge, where the "only" thing that's different from a previous code golf is the task, it's usually not considered a duplicate. ;) (That said, I agree that CnRs are probably more interesting if we change up the CnR-part of the challenge, not the underlying task.)

Comment: @MartinEnder I personally think that the answers from the other challenge could be trivially modified to fit this challenge.  It has nothing to do with the tag IMO

Comment: @NathanMerrill I don't know about others, but none of my four answers could be reasonably reused for this challenge.

Comment: Good luck everyone! I am really glad that you have decided to reopen this. Looking forward to see interesting answers!

Comment: Is it okay if for large values there are rounding errors due to the inaccuracy of floating point numbers at that size?

Comment: @fəˈnɛtɪk yes, of course. The decimal precision really shouldn't matter that much for large values

Comment: Max expected input is 7131.55. It might be helpful to have that in the post.

Comment: I mentioned that the result is lower than **2^32**, so I think it is not necessary @fəˈnɛtɪk

Comment: I had written my code to work for an input up to 2^32... Which is why I asked about rounding errors, got rather off the mark at that point

Comment: Do the robbers need to use the same rounding method as the cops?

Comment: Not necessarily, as long as it works @Leo

Comment: Can languages that do not natively support decimal numbers (Brainfuck, as an example) support only Integer output?

Comment: Well, that's kind of unfair @ATaco, but I will accept that if you specify in your answer.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:code-golf]?

Comment: @RomanGräf because the **shortest** safe answer wins

Comment: Oh, I only read the winning condition of the robbers thread.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder: can the input be 0?

Comment: Yes, it can. The corresponding output is `0`

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder: The rules already say "you can assume n is always positive" which to me means that 0 does not need to be handled. Are you sure you want to change it?

Comment: 0 is considered positive for this challenge @tehtmi

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder: is there a constraint on the performance? As in, is it acceptable for an answer to take a somewhat longer time to return?

Comment: @user4867444 On a standard computer, it should not take longer than 15 seconds to execute

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder OK thanks

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder so no accepted answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 05AB1E, 20 bytes - safe

Another totally different approach from my previous answers.

```
****++/133DDFPTs}¹¹Ð
```

No rounding.

**Example runs**

```
In   -> Out
0    -> 0
4    -> 32.0
6    -> 88.18163074019441
25   -> 3125.0
7131 -> 4294138928.896773
```

I have no doubt @Emigna is going to crack it in a jiffy, but eh, one has to try! :-D

---

**Solution**

```
D1TFÐ*D¹3*+s3*¹+/*}P
```

This is using the fact that this sequence:

u_0 = 1, u_{n+1} = u_n * (u_n ^ 2 + 3 x) / (3 u_n ^ 2 + x)

converges to sqrt(x), and cubically fast at that (sorry, didn't find how to format math equations in PCG).

**Detailed explanation**

```
D1TFÐ*D¹3*+s3*¹+/*}P
D1                   # Duplicate the input, then push a 1: stack is now [x, x, 1] (where x is the input)
  TF                 # 10 times (enough because of the cubic convergence) do
    Ð                # triplicate u_n
     *               # compute u_n ^ 2
      D              # and duplicate it
       ¹3*+          # compute u_n ^ 2 + 3 x
           s         # switch that last term with the second copy of u_n ^ 2
            3*¹+     # compute 3 u_n ^ 2 + x
                /    # compute the ratio (u_n ^ 2 + 3 x) / (3 u_n ^ 2 + x)
                 *   # compute u_n * (u_n ^ 2 + 3 x) / (3 u_n ^ 2 + x), i.e. u_{n+1}, the next term of the sequence
                  }  # end of the loop
                   P # compute the product of the whole stack, which at that point contains u_10 (a sufficiently good approximation of sqrt(x)), and the 2 copies of the input from the initial D: we get x ^ 2 * sqrt(x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@@9iGOJ2eIKWy6GdxlraxcZah3Zq62vVBvz/bwYA)

Answer (score 18):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 44 bytes ([cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/116254/45151))

```python
'**:(((paraboloid / rabid,mad,immoral))):**'
```

No rounding. Floating point accuracy.

Comment: Come on, this deserves more points, it's so creative! There is symmetry, and all words are real words.

Comment: If I didn't make any silly mistakes... [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/116254/15858)

Answer (score 11):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 12 bytes ([cracked by @tehtmi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115451/36398))

```
'Un&0P'/^:+1
```

No rounding; uses floating point.

Intended solution (different from that found by @tehtmi):

> `:&+n10U'P'/^`

#### Explanation

> `:&+     % Create a matrix of size n × n, where n is implicit input`
> `n       % Number of elements. Gives n^2`
> `10U     % 10 squared. Gives 100`
> `'P'     % 'P' (ASCII code 80)`
> `/       % Divide. Gives 1.25`
> `^       % Power. Implicit display`

Comment: [Crack?](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115451/49958)

Comment: @tehtmi Indeed! Well done! My intended solution was different; I just posted it

Answer (score 10):

## [Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda/tree/roda-0.12), 28 bytes ([Cracked by @tehtmi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115449/49958))

```
 (),.025^^cdfhnnnopprstuu{|}
```

Note the space at the beginning. No rounding, but it uses floating point numbers so precision is limited.

Comment: Is this an anonymous function, or a "full" function?

Comment: @KritixiLithos if the cop does not want to give clues, it is not supposed to

Comment: [Cracked?](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115449/49958)

Answer (score 10):

### Perl, 42 bytes (Safe)

There are 41 bytes of code and `-p` flag (no other flags).

```perl
/"/4~~r..rso4r<_$4va=eg1de|i/h0-&$c={}l+"
```

The result isn't rounded (or rather rounded up to the same point Perl would have round up by doing `$_ = (sqrt $_) * ($_ ** 2)`).

**Solution:**

> `$_=eval".i44<4}{|~"=~s/./chr-10+ord$\&/gre`
>  (without the `\` before the `&` - markdown spoiler seems to dislike `$` followed by `&`)
>  [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl5#U1YsSC3KUdAt@K8Sb5talpijpJdpYmJjUltdU6dkW1esr6efnFGka2ignV@UoqKmn16U@v@/JQA)

**Explanation:**

> `.i44<4}{|~` is `$_**2*sqrt` but with every character replaced by the character with its ascii code + 10. (ascii code of `$` is `36`, so it becomes `.` whose ascii code is `46`, etc.).
>  The purpose of `s/./chr-10+ord$\&/gre` is then to undo this transformation: it replaces each character by the character with ascii code 10 lower. (`chr-10+ord$\&` is probably clearer as `chr(ord($\&)-10)` where `chr` returns the character corresponding to an ascii code, and `ord` returns the ascii code corresponding to a character).
>  finally, `eval` evaluates this string, and thus computes the result, which is stored in `$_`, which is implicitly printed at the end thanks to `-p` flag.

Comment: True. I was trying to edit quickly because I saw 4 reopen votes and hoped to get the question fixed before the 5th was cast. If the question had been left in the sandbox until it was ready, it would have been better for all involved.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Sure, no problem, and anyway it was bold so fairly visible (I wasn't blaming anyone, but merely pointing a minor flow (that I corrected right away (introducing typos in the process))). And I couldn't agree more about the sandbox part.

Comment: can you explain it a bit?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc You mean if I can give you a little bit of help to crack it? mmh... the code starts with `$_=`. And there is a `eval` somewhere. (that's not a lot but I feel I can't give you more without giving you too much information)

Answer (score 8):

## Octave, 43 bytes (Safe)

```
$'()*+,-/23579:[]aelnouv'*,-23:[]lu',-23]',
```

This is a script that requires input from the command line (it's not a function). It's floating point accuracy (so no rounding).

**Solution:**

> `eval(-[5,-2:3,-3:2]+['nlouu*$$',39,']2/7'])`

**Explanation:**

> `eval( <string> )  % Evaluated the string inside the brackets and executes it`  
> Everything inside the `eval` call gets evaluated to `input('')^2.5` 
> **How?**
> `-[5,-2:3,-3:2]           % A vector: [-5, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2]`
> `['nlouu**$$',39,']2/7']   % This is a string: nlouu**$  concatenated with the number` 
> `.                        % 39 (ASCII ']'), and ']2/7'. Thus, combined: 'nlouu**$$']2/7'`
> Adding the first vector to this string will convert it to the integer vector: 
> `[105, 110, 112, 117, 116, 40, 39, 39, 41, 94, 50, 46, 53]`
> `eval` implicitly converts this to a string, and these numbers just so happens to be:
> `input('')^2.5`

Comment: This was hard. Well done!

Answer (score 7):

## C, 50 bytes ([Cracked by fergusq](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115176/8927))

```
%(())   ,-12225;>\\aaabbdddeeefffllnoooprrttuuuuw{
```

Uses standard IEEE754 rounding. As noted by fergusq's answer, may require `-lm` depending on your compiler.

Comment: [Cracked?](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115176/66323)

Comment: @fergusq correct, and almost exactly what I had. Well done; I thought I'd left enough red-herrings in there to keep people busy a lot longer!

Comment: @Dave Wow, that looks like a syntax error at first.

Answer (score 6):

## Swift - 64 bytes (Safe)

```
prot Fdnufi;nooitamunc xetgru(->atl)Ior:n{tFn pg,F(ao.o25t)(w)l}
```

No rounding, and displays a `.0` even if the result is an integer.

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica, 131 bytes, non-competing?, [cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115146/66104)

*This has been **cracked by [@lanlock4](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115146/66104)**! However, I still have internet points to bestow on someone who finds the original solution, where all the characters are actually needed....*

```
f[y_]:=With[{x=@@@@@@#####^^&&&(((()))){{}}111111,,+-/y},Print[#,".",IntegerString[Round@#2,10,3]]&@@QuotientRemainder[1000x,1000]]
```

This is intended as a puzzle. Although you may use the above characters however you want, I certainly intend for the answer to follow the form

```
f[y_]:=With[{x=
    @@@@@@#####^^&&&(((()))){{}}111111,,+-/y
},Print[#,".",IntegerString[Round@#2,10,3]]&@@QuotientRemainder[1000x,1000]]
```

where the first and third lines are just a wrapper to make the rounding and display legal (it writes every output to exactly three decimal places, rounded), and the second line is the scrambled version of the guts of the code. Sample outputs:

```
6 -> 88.182
9 -> 243.000
9999 -> 9997500187.497
```

(Mathematica is non-free software, but there is a [Wolfram sandbox](https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com) where it is possible to test modest amounts of code. For example, cutting and pasting the code

```
f[y_]:=With[{x=
    y^2.5
},Print[#,".",IntegerString[Round@#2,10,3]]&@@QuotientRemainder[1000x,1000]]
```

defines a function, which you can subsequently call like `f@6` or `f[9]`, that does the same thing as the unscrambled version of the code above. So does this really have to be non-competing?)

Comment: [Cracked it!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115146/66104)

Answer (score 4):

## C#, 172 bytes ([Cracked by SLuck49](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/115034/robbers-square-times-square-root/115332#115332))

```
       (((((())))))***,,,,......1225;;;;;;<====>CFLMMMMMPPPRSSSSSWaaaaaaabbbbcccddddddeeeeeeeeeeegghiiiiiiiillllllmmnnnnnnnooooooooqqqqrrrssssssssstttttttttuuuuuuuvvwyy{{}}
```

This code is a full program.

There are seven space characters at the start.

The input is read form STDIN and printed to STDOUT. The result is in `double`, no rounding done.

Original Code ungolfed:

```
using System;
using S = System.Console;

class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var t = S.ReadLine();
        double q = int.Parse(t);
        Func<double, double, double> M = Math.Pow;
        S.Write(M(q, 2 * .25) * M(q * q, 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115332/32628)

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell, 16 bytes ([Cracked by @nimi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115104/61405))

```
()*...25=eglopxx
```

No particular rounding

Answer (score 4):

## R, 28 bytes ([Cracked by @Flounderer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115132/26905))

```
funny(p1)-tio(^*^)/pc(2)<p2;
```

Standard R floating-point accuracy.

Comment: Is this it? http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115132/26905

Comment: @Flounderer Yes, it is.

Answer (score 4):

### Ohm, 11 bytes

```
M ⁿ¡D¼½;+1I
```

Use with `-c` flag. Uses CP-437 encoding.

Comment: I'm sorry, but are you quite sure this is correct?

Comment: Now that no one has cracked it in the imparted time, mind sharing your solution please? I'm very curious :)

Comment: For now, this is the shortest answer considered safe. I will accept it, but if you do not post your original code in 5 days, I will uncheck this, since I am not sure this is possible. EAGER too see your **solution**

Comment: I've currently lost my solution. I will try to find it,but its in my old mobile which has a broken plug.

Comment: By the way, you generally don't need the `-c` flag in PPCG submissions unless you explicitly need to use a CP-437 encoded byte stream.

Comment: @RomanGräf try to find your solution, please. Otherwise I will uncheck this...

Comment: @RomanGräf : ping? Still very eager to see that solution :)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder : how much longer are we going to wait for the solution?

Comment: He shared it, but has deleted that comment

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder : really? That's a shame... I'd very much like to see it, I tried to crack this thing for a good amount of time :)

Comment: @RomanGräf please repost your initial codr

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder : I must say it makes me a little sad that the accepted solution doesn't even bother giving its original code. One could have just posted some random short string and "won". Not very respectful of the time spent by the all the other people who played by the rules.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2, 60 Bytes ([Cracked by @notjagan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115140/63641))

```
 3n0)4  5)594p3(p5*5i9t4542)0/*((8(t.84- 90945 u)i*48/95n8r8
```

No rounding involved. Accurate up to 10 decimal digits.

Comment: [Cracked!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115140/63641)

Answer (score 3):

## [Inform 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inform#Inform_7), 71 bytes ([Cracked by @Ilmari Karonen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/115034/robbers-square-times-square-root/115135#115135))

```
""()**-..:[]
                 RT
aaaabeeeffilmmnnnnnooooooqrrrrrssstuuy
```

The code includes 17 spaces and 2 new lines.
This is a full Infrom 7 program defining a function that prints the result with a precision of 5 decimal places.

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115135)

Answer (score 3):

### Haskell, 64 bytes, ([cracked by Laikoni](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115223/34531))

```
$$$$$$(((((())))))**,...0<<<>>>[]cccccdddeffiiiiilloopppprrsstuu
```

Standard Haskell floating point operations.

My original version is:

> product.((($succ$cos$0)(flip(**).)[id,recip])).flip(id)

Comment: [Cracked!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115223/56433)

Comment: @Laikoni: well done!

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES7), 20 bytes ([Cracked by @IlmariKaronen](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115142))

```
****..22255666=>____
```

Standard JavaScript precision.

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115142) (Oops, posted in the wrong thread at first.)

Comment: Such a clever approach! +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

### R, 19 bytes [(Cracked by @Steadybox)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115136/26905)

```
mensana(4*5*c(.1)):
```

Standard rounding

### R, 33 bytes [(Cracked by @plannapus)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115230/26905)

```
(rofl(17)^coins(2*e)/pisan(10))--
```

### R, 31 bytes [(Cracked by @plannapus)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115993/26905)

`` h=f`l`u`n`c`t`i`o`n([],[])^(.9) ``

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115136/61405) the 19-byte answer.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115230/6741) the 33-byte solution.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115993/6741) the 31-byte solution!

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3.6, 59 bytes

```
ba(,b5,d' (,a/([m:'-)oa)(bl*aadplma dba](r)d )l*d,:)*m:-mml
```

No rounding. Floating point accuracy.

Comment: Really, 3 lambdas?

Answer (score 3):

## [Fourier](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fourier), <strike>124</strike>  119 Bytes

```
((()))*******--011111<=>>>HHINNNN^^^eeehhhhkkkkmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmossuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu{{{{{{{{{{}}}}}}}}}}~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

There are no whitespaces or newline characters.

Square root is rounded to the nearest whole number because Fourier doesn't seem to handle anything other than integers (and since @ATaco got permission, I hope this is ok)

fixed an editing mistake, if you were already cracking this, the previous was functional

Realized that I had misunderstood part of the code, and was using more characters than I needed to

If I missed anything let me know

Answer (score 3):

## Octave, 30 bytes (Safe)

```
(((((())))))**++/:@eeeiiijmsu~
```

A bit simpler than my first one. Shouldn't be too hard, but it's hopefully a fun puzzle.

Comment: No `^`? Hmmm...

Comment: Came up with this `@(e)(e**((i/(i+i))+~sum(e:j)))` but it's only `n^1.5`...this one's tricky.

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript, 123 bytes, [Cracked by notjagan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115108/64505)

```
 """"""((((((((()))))))))********,--.....//2;;======>>Seeeeeeegggggggggggghhhhhhhhhhhilllllnnnnnnnnnnorrrsstttttttttttttu{}
```

This code is a full function

There is one space character at the very start of the list of characters

The rounding of this answer is the floating point precision for Javascript, accuracy is within 10^-6 for every answer.

Got shorter because the precision didn't need to be maintained quite as high as I thought it did.

I had realized that it would be much easier to solve than I initially had made it but it was already there :P

**Initial code:**

```
g=t=>t-(t*t-n)/("le".length*t);e=h=>{n=h*h*h*h*h,s=2**(n.toString("ng".length).length/"th".length);return g(g(g(g(g(s)))))}
```

Newtons method, applied 5 times from the closest power of 2

Answer (score 2):

### [OCaml](http://www.ocaml.org/), 13 bytes ([Cracked by @Dada](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/115034/robbers-square-times-square-root/115078#115078))

```
2*fn-5f>f*u .
```

No rounding (within IEEE 754 scope).

Comment: [cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115078/55508).

Answer (score 2):

### Excel VBA, 59 bytes (Safe)

```
?(())*..//11124AAAAFPSW[[]]^acceehiiiiklnnnnoooppqrrstttttu
```

No particular rounding.
Uses the Immediate Window.

Answer (score 2):

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), 6 Bytes ([Cracked by @notjagan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115286/63641))

```
š2]^*\
```

No rounding, displays many decimal places.
Does not display any for an integer solution.

Comment: Does this really perform `n²√n`? I can easily get it to calculate `n² + √n`, but I can't for the life of me see how you got the terms to multiply.

Comment: @notjagan me too... have been trying for 2 hours to crack it and nothing works. ATaco are you sure that the source is correct?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Ah, you're quite correct. Sorry for wasting your collective times! Please see the edited source.

Comment: Now it makes sense!

Comment: A bit late because I was busy, but [cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115286/63641).

Answer (score 2):

## Octave, 42 bytes (Safe)

```
((((()))))+,,,-//01111111@[]^mnooorrssst~~
```

No rounding. Floating point accuracy.

#### Intended solution

> `@(s)norm(roots([-1,~1,s^(10/(1+1))]),1/~1)`
>  
>  
>  [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#@@@gUayZl1@Uq1GUn19SrBGta6hTZ6hTHKdhaKCvYahtqKkZq6ljqF9nqPk/Ma9Yw0zzPwA)

Comment: Was this close? `f=@(s)s^norm(roots([1,2.5,1]),1)`? I didn't find a way to make those remaining numbers and `+-~~` become `2.5`. I had some other attempts that were quite similar (changed the numbers a bit), but I couldn't get it correct.

Comment: @StewieGriffin It was! I have posted the intended solution

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3.6 - 52 bytes ([Cracked by @xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115161/67047))

```
f=lambda x:x**125*77*8+8/5/((('aafoort.hipie.xml')))
```

Standard Python rounding

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115161/20260)

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, 35 bytes (cracked by [xsot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115171/18535))

```
'a'0-a<2<e<2<l<3<v<4<4<4<5<5<6>7{9}
```

No rounding. Floating point accuracy.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115171/45268)

Answer (score 2):

### C#, 112 bytes  (cracked by [Emigna](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115178/67504))

```
     ((((())))),.....25;;;=CCLMMPPPRSWaaaaaaabbbccdddeeeeeeeeghiiiiiillllmnnnnnooooooorrrsssssssstttttuuvvwy{{}}
```

no rounding done

```
using System;
class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var b=double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write(Math.Pow(b,2.5));
    }
}
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115178/47066)

Comment: You are free to add more cops if you have more ideas, but you should post them in separate answers instead of adding to an existing one.

Comment: Ok: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115492/67504

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 47 bytes

```
)*.2555BFHIJJKKKPQRST``cgghilnstwx}«¹¹Áöž‚„…………
```

Does not round, uses floating point accuracy.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115202/47066)

Answer (score 2):

### CJam, 8 bytes ([Cracked by E<s>n</s>mig<s>m</s>na](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115203/56341))

```
WYdYl##+
```

No rounding. Uses double precision.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115203/47066)

Answer (score 2):

## [Fireball](https://github.com/okx-code/Fireball), 8 bytes ([Cracked by Roman Gräf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115197/34718))

```
♥1Z*^²/♥
```

Does not round, uses floating point precision.

Code surrounded with hearts ;)

Should pretty easy to crack, once you have a look into Fireball.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115197/56341)

Answer (score 2):

## R, 32 bytes ([Cracked by @plannapus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115227/61405))

```
i=na*0.5f*n(2*s*cos(t))*22*s*12u
```

Standard floating-point accuracy.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115227/6741).

Answer (score 2):

### Excel, 26 bytes

```
=(())*//11122AAAIINPQRSST^
```

No rounding.

*Note: As Excel is paid software, this works also in free LibreOffice*

Comment: Is there a way to run this without buying Excel?  Currently it is the consensus that non free languages cannot be used in cops and robbers.

Comment: Should work in free Libreoffice, but I'll check and reach back.

Comment: Works just fine.

Comment: Cracked http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/115034/robbers-square-times-square-root/115276#115276

Comment: @WheatWizard, not relevant anymore, but I think the consensus is: [Non-free languages can be used, but should be marked as non-competing](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11728/31516).

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript + [paper.js](http://paperjs.org), 210 bytes (safe)

This one's fun. No comments for you, and no strings either.

paper.js is a vector graphics framework. This is a full program that takes input via a prompt and outputs graphically, because it's possible. There is no rounding and floating-point accuracy (I think).
[Reference](http://paperjs.org/reference/global/)
[Try code here](http://sketch.paperjs.org)

```
Math.tan(prompt(a,0));
leg Rave, ew(0,0),ectoPlasm = Real new qrt(;
marvin atTax M(en) in vr;tent * hat.o = Mat
nottet near(0a,a) w cgee;
brown.cern(lantern) ;( w 0,0.art;vict.o brace
r=v=,h.c.)an=.flClr= Cor0)
```

Edit: Just noticed (my fault for not reading properly)

> The shortest safe answer by the end of April will be considered the winner.

Well, oops.

Original solution:

```
var a = prompt(0,0);
var r = new Rectangle(0,0,a,a).area;
var t = new Rectangle(0,0,Math.cbrt(a),Math.sqrt(Math.cbrt(a))).area;
var n = new PointText(view.center);
n.content = r * t;
n.fillColor = new Color(0);
```

[Try code here](http://sketch.paperjs.org)

Answer (score 2):

## [NO!](https://github.com/ValyrioCode/NO), 41 bytes (Cracked by [Emigna](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115386/66833))

NOOO! NO! can finally compete! <s>Although no-one will be bothered to crack this anyway :(</s>

Anyway *sigh* here's the code:

```
NNNOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO??
nnno!
```

Full list of commands [here](https://github.com/ValyrioCode/NO/blob/master/Doc/List%20of%20Commands.md).
Coded in Python so uses Python rounding.

NOOOOOOOOO!!!!!!!! Someone cracked it. (Curse you Emigna!) (just kidding!)

Comment: Introducing a new language will be fun ... Cannot wait ro strugle to crack it

Comment: Post another answer to *NOT!* mess up the two @ThisGuy

Comment: I think you mean "consonants" in your documentation (not constants).

Comment: @Dave D'oh! ☺️

Comment: hmm, what's the canonical version of your interpreter for this challenge? Current master doesn't compile due to a typo on line 162 (there's also a typo on line 163 and missing `self.` on 149).

Comment: Guessing not required for this challenge, but bug report: the condition on 174 doesn't match the documentation: `O` on its own will be skipped, not interpreted as 0.1

Comment: @Dave corrected

Comment: [Cracked?](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115386/47066)

Answer (score 2):

### C, 115 bytes, ([Cracked by @tehtmi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115477/44706))

```
""%&&((((((()))))))******++++,..//01122233388;;;;;;<====>>   bbbdddeeeefffggillllllllllnnnnnnnnoooooooooooprrtuuu{}
```

Notice that it does include 3 spaces.

Always outputs 3 exact decimals, rounded to the closest thousandth.

Should be rather fun to crack as it doesn't involve any built-in to compute powers or square roots, as opposed to most (cracked) solutions so far.

Example run (which also gives you a few small hints):

```
int main() {
  int n[] = {4, 6, 9, 25};
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    printf("%i => ", n[i]);
    o(n[i]);
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

outputs:

```
4 => 32.000
6 => 88.182
9 => 243.000
25 => 3125.000
```

Tested with both gcc and clang, with no compilation flag needed.

---

It's been cracked; the original solution was

```
o(double n){long o=2.303e18+(*(long*)&n>>1);double l=*(double*)&o;for(o=2;o++<8;)l=(l+n/l)/2;printf("%.3f",l*n*n);}
```

which uses a magic constant in the same spirit as [the infamous fast inverse square root algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root#Overview_of_the_code) to do just a handful of Newton iterations (as opposed to several thousands in the cracked solution)

Comment: It could actually be 3 bytes shorter, at a cost of completely sacrificing performance though :) (as in, becomes really, really slow)

Comment: [Crack?](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115477/49958) Probably not exactly what you're going for, but maybe similar and I think it is okay.

Comment: @tehtmi not quite, see my comment there (your solution does not return correctly for input 0)

Answer (score 2):

## [HODOR](https://github.com/ValyrioCode/Hodor/blob/master/English/List%20of%20Commands.md), 172 bytes, [Cracked by Emigna](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115331/67716)

```
Walder
Hodor Hodor Hodor Hodor Hodor Hodor
Hodor Hodor Hodor Hodor Hodor
Hodor Hodor Hodor Hodor
Hodor Hodor Hodor
Hodor Hodor
Hodor
hodor hodor
HODOR HODOR!!!!!!!,,,,,,..?
```

let me know if I missed anything

Comment: Nope, this is scrambled

Comment: just approved your edit, I wrote this up last night... I think the interpreter I was using might have been out of date... I will need to check to make sure the code still works when I get home

Comment: I'm checking it now. See if I can crack it

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115331/47066)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 35 bytes

```
ö£=s‰sr2xöR+RM0`.T"YVBYCDž„¨¨"6£H-L
```

This one took me a while to make.

There's some double quotes in there, so you can surround as much of the code as you want in them.

No rounding, decimal point precision.

Answer (score 2):

## Lua 5.3, 110 bytes (safe)

```
((((()))))**,,,,,-....=====>~             aaaaaaaaacddddeeeffhhhiiiiiiilllmmnnnnnnooopppppprrrrrrrsssssssstttt
```

Calculations are standard using Lua numbers (ie double in common implementations). Tested using PUC-Rio interpreter. (I hope I didn't do anything bad, but I think it is reasonable...)

This is a full program with input from the command line.

Original solution:

> `for a,r in pairs(math)do l,s=pcall(r,-math.pi)if s~=s and a>=(i or a)then i,p=a,r end end s=...print(s*s*p(s))`

Explanation:

> `math.sqrt` is retrieved from the math library by looping through the `math` table and looking for functions that return NaN (and don't throw an error) when applied to negative pi. There are only a few functions like this, and `sqrt` is alphabetically last.

Answer (score 2):

## 05AB1E, 23 bytes ([Cracked by Emigna](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/115034/robbers-square-times-square-root/115773#115773))

A totally different approach than my previous answers :)

```
$++/02;@DDDGHP\rrszz}¹ž
```

No rounding.

**Example runs**

```
In   -> Out
0    -> 0
4    -> 32.0
6    -> 88.18163074019441
25   -> 3125.0
7131 -> 4294138928.8967724
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115773/47066)

Comment: Dammit :-D ! This wasn't the intended solution, mine was `$žHGDzrDz0@+2s/r+;}\¹DP`, using the convergent sequences `u_0 = 1, v_0 = x, u_(n+1) = 2 / (1/u_n + 1/v_n), v_(n+1) = (u_n + v_n) /2` to compute the square root. But very well done!

Comment: The thing is, it's hard to come up with an approximation method that can't be tweaked back into Newtons' iterations, mmh...

Comment: Oooh, that was a cool implementation. I figured my crack wasn't the intended :)

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript, <strike>15</strike> 17 bytes, [Cracked by @Emigna](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/115034/robbers-square-times-square-root/116237#116237)

```
(x=>x****-125*10)
```

Solution:

> `x=>x**(25*10**-1)`

## Javascript, 18 bytes, Again, [Cracked.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/115034/robbers-square-times-square-root/116240#116240)

```
x=>x**-(!3.5++)[];
```

Solution:

> `x=>x**(3-!+[]+.5);`

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/116237/47066). I was really wondering how to do it without the parenthesis ;)

Comment: [Cracked 2nd](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/116240/47066)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3.6 - 15 bytes ([Cracked by Kritixi Lithos](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/115034/robbers-square-times-square-root/115065#115065))

```
axx 2*d:b.*5mal
```

Standard rounding precision of Python

Comment: [Cracked!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115065/41805)

Comment: @KritixiLithos well done +1

Answer (score 1):

## C++, 100 bytes ([Cracked by @fergusq](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115073/66323))

```
#.leiha2dm"
tuchn"crmueie<linaatt#dso
fameng pcae sli;t>dt nnsiuno;s mnpti;ouic(<){n(a;>w<n>n)co.,5}
```

Standard C++ rounding precision

Comment: [Cracked!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115073/66323)

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 44 Bytes ([Cracked by @fəˈnɛtɪk](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115076/64505))

```
np5w***i0(0(0r0n0t+iarn00p0)_(0tu00i50.0)) t
```

Has accuracy up to 10 decimal digits (I think). No rounding involved and there is a space involved.

Comment: [Cracked!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115076/64505)

Comment: @fəˈnɛtɪk you should edit the answer you've cracked. Well done!

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 19 bytes [(Cracked by @math_junkie)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115101/65425)

```
)>,/2(=addd.hmoptw5
```

This is a function of type `Int=>Double`.

Comment: [Cracked!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115101/65425)

Answer (score 1):

## C, 60 bytes ([Cracked by @Dave](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115113/61405))

```
1(root, flat*fat bern**lotr);pw(f{bus(--q.b4/q0*1-2)})(b>1)b
```

Standard C float accuracy.

Comment: Cracked: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115113/8927

Answer (score 1):

## 05AB1E, 4 bytes ([Cracked by @Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/115034/robbers-square-times-square-root/115106#115106))

Must be really easy to crack, but I'll still post it here

```
n*t¹
```

Normal rounding

Answer (score 1):

## 05AB1E, 23 bytes (Cracked by [Emigna](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115247/67702))

Another try

```
A9n*¥="'q?:@->%t#[{¹!.
```

Normal rounding

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115247/47066)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 22 bytes, Cracked by [user4867444](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115760/47066)

```
+/;DDDFLPT_nz}©®¹¹¹Ïè›
```

**Example runs**

```
In -> Out
0  -> 0
4  -> 32.0
6  -> 88.18163074019441
```

**Original solution**

> `LnD¹›_Ï®©èTFD¹/z+;}¹DP`

Comment: [Cracked!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115760/44706)

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript (ES6), 39 bytes ([Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115360/12474))

```
(((())))*....57===>Mabcefghlllloprttxxx
```

The rounding is normal floating point precision for Javascript.

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115360/12474)

Answer (score 1):

## [HODOR](https://github.com/ValyrioCode/Hodor), 198 bytes [(Cracked by wwj)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115292/66833)

*NB: Had to correct the code!*

Uses the brand-new `hodor` command (Updated Saturday)! Yes, I know I'm not supposed to say but it's pretty obvious anyway and (as far as I know) I'm the only person who can code in Hodor so worth some help :)

This is the code: and the full list of commands is [here](https://github.com/ValyrioCode/Hodor/blob/master/Docs/List%20of%20Commands.md)

```
H!HDHrlrHrhoooo!h, oo!do ordoH!oHHd
dodHrodorooooHdddoooOOo ddro roorrro.r,H
ooO ooHr,
HdHo oo H!O?Hd, oo,, Hdodhd oor, dd!HHrDo aod
rdroHdH,HrRr
 o o RHrdHoo,oro Hr
oo
oHoer o r oddodo,rr
rdd!WrH d
```

Comment: How do I run the Hodor interpreter?

Comment: @Emigna working on a file that will run from command line but for now will add a note in README (English version)

Comment: Is there perhaps a bug on row 118 in the interpreter? I can't get my program to work without changing that. Also, `h` should be in `VALID_CHARS` right?

Comment: @Enigma What version of Python are you using. I've fixed it btw

Comment: I was using python 3.

Comment: @Emigna Yeah it needs either `[]` or `()` around it to work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56598/discussion-between-emigna-and-this-guy).

Comment: The link to HODOR is dead

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES7), 24 bytes (Safe)

```
()+01488M``aabeiijlooqtv
```

Standard 64 bit floating point rounding.

---

#### Solution

> `` eval(atob`8j0+8ioqMi41`) ``

#### Tests

```js
console.log(eval(atob`8j0+8ioqMi41`)(0));    // 0
console.log(eval(atob`8j0+8ioqMi41`)(1));    // 1
console.log(eval(atob`8j0+8ioqMi41`)(2));    // 5.656854249492381
console.log(eval(atob`8j0+8ioqMi41`)(4));    // 32
console.log(eval(atob`8j0+8ioqMi41`)(10));   // 316.22776601683796
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Stacked](https://tio.run/nexus/stacked), 64 bytes

```
:u#{`E2t#tv',lnp~.iuP#2qr+t,'3m3em`,#9''.::mluls on\ts r:a\:+.S0
```

Good luck.

Result for `6`: `88.181630740194411535`.

Comment: Maybe linking to https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked would be more helpful.

Comment: @user4867444 If you click on "stacked" in the link above it gets your there anyhow.

Comment: Takes me to https://tio.run/nexus/stacked rather, which is not super helpful to learn about the language?

Comment: @user4867444 Perhaps my wording is confusing. On the tio.run page, clicking on "stacked" gets you to the github. [Shown in this image](http://image.prntscr.com/image/35023b30561d4f7fb03c26403c837cf5.png) Admittedly, it's a tad convoluted.

Answer (score 1):

## bash, 158 bytes

This program requires a 64 bit processor to function. Pass input number as argument; result on stdout. I believe rounding is floor function. This program actually does decimal output. If you got integer only keep trying.

```
^=======|       -!
///////......
''(((((((((((())))))))))))
[]$$$$$$$$$****
\\\\\\
#++
000000000000
111111222
bcdddeeeehhhiill
nn
NNNNNNoooOOOOOOO
sssSSSS
tw
```

Answer (score 1):

### C#, 135 bytes (cracked by [SLuck49](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115809/67504))

```
      (((((()))))),,-..../11;;;CCEILMMMPPPRRSSWaaaaaaacccdddeeeeeeeeggghiiiiiiiillllmmnnnnnnnnoooooooorrsssssssssssttttttttuuuvwyy{{}}
```

no rounding done
([First try](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115174/67504))

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115809/32628) This was fun.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript (ES7), 53 bytes (safe)

```
(((())))*++++,,,/0233346=====>>[[]]aaaabbbccelootttuv
```

The rounding is normal floating point precision for Javascript.

Tested this in the latest Chrome and FF.

---

#### Solution

> `u=>(o=(t,c,a=o+c,b=a[t])=>eval(a[42]+b+b+3*30/t))(36)`
>
>
>  This works because `a=o+c` is `'(t,c,a=o+c,b=a[t])=>eval(a[42]+b+b+3*30/t)undefined'`. 
>
>    So `a[42]='u', a[36]='*', 3*30/36=2.5`, making `eval('u**2.5')`.

#### Tests

```js
var f=u=>(o=(t,c,a=o+c,b=a[t])=>eval(a[42]+b+b+3*30/t))(36);
console.log(f(0));    // 0
console.log(f(1));    // 1
console.log(f(2));    // 5.656854249492381
console.log(f(4));    // 32
console.log(f(10));   // 316.22776601683796
```

Answer (score 1):

## 05AB1E, 15 bytes, ([Cracked by Emigna](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/115034/robbers-square-times-square-root/115767#115767))

```
+/01;DDDFMPs}¹ž
```

Normal rounding

**Example runs**

```
In   -> Out
0    -> 0
4    -> 32.0
6    -> 88.18163074019441
25   -> 3125.0
7131 -> 4294138928.896773
```

Comment: [Cracked](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115767/47066), right back at ya :P

Comment: @Emigna: eh, I figured it was only a question of time, same method ;) good job!

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2.7, 174 bytes

```
_cc*gnta(dkree_rtrto._i9kuc_ l5_r_cctbimWka(Wihlkeu_5_eur_rri_keeluc4clrp ..u_)(HohhH)ap5o(trbnord_ir9/*in)_clrikroap.ie.tg_obkfkseeeel*in2Hkdu*ffmo4lWlrncde_22);doodt a49 hu
```

Answer (score 1):

## 05AB1E, 27 bytes - safe

Yet another totally different approach from my previous answers.

```
(/1DFFOOPT`ins}}©®¹¹Ðèëž‚‚‹
```

No rounding.

**Example runs**

```
In   -> Out
0    -> 0
4    -> 32.0
6    -> 88.18163074019441
25   -> 3125.0
7131 -> 4294138928.896773
```

---

**Solution**

```
Ð(‚žFFDO©n¹‹i`T/ë1è®s}‚}O¹P
```

This is simply computing the square root with a trivial (and very dumb) trial-and-error strategy...

**Detailed explanation**

```
Ð(‚žFFDO©n¹‹i`T/ë1è®s}‚}O¹P
Ð(‚                         # triplicate the input, reverse the sign of the last copy, and wrap the last 2 items in a list, which going forward is going to be the list of our current sqrt approximation and of the next decrement in our dumb search (so it starts at [x, -x])
   žFF                      # 16384(!) times, do
      D                     # duplicate the current [value, decrement] list
       O©                   # compute the sum value + decrement, and also save it in the register
         n                  # compute the square of that potential new approximation of the square root
          ¹‹                # and compare it with the input
            i               # if our new approximation is smaller than the actual square root, then
             `              # push the flattened [value, decrement] list to the stack as value, decrement
              T/            # and divide our decrement by 10
                ë           # else (our new approximation is still bigger than the actual square root, then)
                 1è         # extract the current decrement from the list
                   ®        # retrieve the new approximation from the register
                    s       # and switch them to again have them in the value, decrement order
                     }      # end of the if
                      ‚     # no matter which branch of the if we went into, the last 2 items of the stack are now the new approximation and the new decrement, in order: wrap them in a list for the next loop iteration
                       }    # end of the loop
                        O   # replaces the output of the loop (the final [value, decrement] list) by its sum, which given the very small value of the decrement at that point is pretty much the same as our final approximation of sqrt(x)
                         ¹  # push another copy of x; the stack is now [x, sqrt(x), x] (where the first x comes from the very first copy of the initial Ð)
                          P # computes the product of the whole stack
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@394gsajhllH97m5ufgfWpl3aOejhp2ZCSH6h1cbHl5xaF1xLVC21v/QzoD//80A)

Answer (score 1):

## Java 7, 224 bytes (safe)

```
      ""&&((((((((()))))))))***++++++,,,,,,,-......//000000001113344556677;;;;;;;;;;<<======>>LLSS[\\\\\]aaaaaaaabbbbcccccccccdddddddddeeeeffffggggggiiiiiiiklllmmmnnnnnnnoooooooopprrrrrrssssssssssssstttttttttttuuuuuuuuvy{{}}
```

Look I know it's a lot of bytes but it's a full java program so you can expect a good portion of it to be basic boiler plate... and surely there are no tricks being employed. Output has 3 decimal places and operates the same as the examples in the challenge. I could probably make this harder but part of the fun is seeing how you end up breaking this and solving it in an unintended way. Good luck!

P.S. that's 6 spaces in case you're curious.

**Example Runs**

```
0    ->          0.000
4    ->         32.000
6    ->         88.182
25   ->       3125.000
7131 -> 4294138928.897
```

Solution:

```
class u{static double s,a,c,n,d,g,t;public static void main(String...u)\u007bd=Long.parseLong(u[0]);n=d/(c+++1);for(;g<(t=13);g++){for(;s<n;s+=c)if(s*s>d&&(s-=c)>0)break;c/=t;}System.out.format("\045\0563\146",s*d*d);}\u007d
```

Ungolfed:

```
class u{
static double s,a,c,n,d,g,t;               // static doubles default to 0.0
public static void main(String...u)\u007b  // had to use 1 or 2 unicode escapes for fun

d=Long.parseLong(u[0]);
n=d/(c+++1);                              // get d/2 while also making c=1

for(;g<(t=13);g++){                       // get 13 decimals of precision
  for(;s<n;s+=c)                          // increment the current decimal position
    if(s*s>d&&(s-=c)>0)break;             // square the current value and make sure we're still below the target
  c/=t;
}
System.out.format("\045\0563\146",s*d*d); // java also has octal string escapes
}
\u007d
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 12 bytes, [Cracked by lyxal](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237661/100664)

```
`25/n:([|eĖĖ
```

Have fun!

Comment: [lol](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237661/78850)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 14 bytes

```
`25/$n:([|tėĖĖ
```

On to round 2!

Comment: Community has flagged this answer as a duplicate of your last answer btw.  Took me a while to spot the difference myself.

Comment: @GrainGhost I made a mistake in the previous, so did another one. I can see why this happened, it's *not* a big difference.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 39 bytes (cracked by [@Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/115034/robbers-square-times-square-root/115083#115083))

```python
q=a(lxt)mh*mprf.hr
ax tttaixxmb :m*asod
```

Standard Python float rounding.

Comment: [Cracked.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/115034/robbers-square-times-square-root/115083#115083)

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 179 bytes, safe

```
(((((((((((((())))))))))))))*****++,,,,,-..///////000000000111112222222222:;;;<=====>>>>?AFM[[[[[[[[[[[]]]]]]]]]]]abbbcdddddeeeeehllllnnnnnnnnnnnnnooooooooooorrrrrsttuuuuuww{{{}}}
```

There is no rounding. The code forms a lambda that takes an `int` and returns a `double`.

---

**Solution**

```
n=>{Func<double[],double>r=null;return(r=(o)=>(Math.Abs(o[1]-o[2])>=0.0000001)?r(new[]{o[0],o[2],(o[2]+(o[0]/o[2]))/2}):o[2])(new[]{n,(n*1d)/2,((n*1d)/2+(n/(n*1d)/2))/2})*(n*n);};
```

**Exploded Solution**

```
(int n) => 
{
    Func<double[], double>r = null;

    r = (double[] o) =>
    { 
        if(Math.Abs(o[1]-o[2]) >= 0.0000001))
        {
            return r(new[]{ o[0], o[2], (o[2] + (o[0] / o[2])) / 2 });
        }
        else
        {
            return o[2];
        }
    };

    var initialO = new[]
    { 
        n, 
        (n * 1d) / 2, 
        ((n * 1d) / 2 + (n / (n * 1d) / 2)) / 2 
    };

    return r(initialO) * (n * n);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3.6 - 64 bytes ([Cracked by user4867444](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/115034/robbers-square-times-square-root/115411#115411))

```
f1;7*x0d/2p6*mm1i*99 5 a o o t(a bphpx:m38af4r*1221=s2rm.0itlpa)
```

Extremely high precision. No rounding.

**ORIGINAL SOLUTION:**

> `from math import pi as p;f=lambda x:x**(p**3/12.402510672119928)`

Comment: [Cracked!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115411/32604)

Comment: @KyleGullion not very creative, but smart. I'll post the original solution shortly

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 61 Bytes (Safe)

No rounding

```
a$rians=)n$$/rnd=aa(*gt$)gg*g)(g)$(r|pg-n(+(;$r($)(tr)=r)ngq.
```

### Original Solution

```
print($argn**(sqrt(((a|n).rd)($g=$argn==$argn))/($g+$g)-$g));
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python 2.7, 41 bytes

```
(sexypint=='pint')**(55.0)**fur==(.3%0%y)
```

rounding done by "%.3f"

Comment: [Cracked!](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115848/64121)